# How do I use hitTestPoint correctly for my player?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to follow a tutorial to help me learn how to create a platform game. However, whenever I test my code my player will go through the background(named back instead of background). I have tried to add more points to stop it from doing this but it just continues. Anyone experienced in hitTestPoint or flash please assist me!

*Look at the Bumping part of my code*

http://as3gametuts.com/2012/01/08/platformer-3/ --- use this.

The background is just the platform where the player stands. The hitTestPoint code should stop the player falling through the platform or going through walls. Sometimes hitTestPoint will work when the player is going very slow.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;

var leftReleased:Boolean = false;
var rightReleased:Boolean = false;
var upReleased:Boolean = false;
var downReleased:Boolean = false;

var xSpeed:int = 10;
var ySpeed:int = 10;

var scrollX:int = 0;
var scrollY:int = 0;

var speedConstant:int = 5;
var friction:Number = 0.95;

var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
var upBumping:Boolean = false;
var downBumping:Boolean = false;

var upleftBumping:Boolean = false;
var uprightBumping:Boolean = false;
var downrightBumping:Boolean = false;
var downleftBumping:Boolean = false;

var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30, -55)
var upleftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30, -87)
var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30, -55)
var uprightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30, -87)
var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, -120)
var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0)
var downrightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30, -27)
var downleftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30, -27)



function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        leftPressed = true;
      } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
            rightPressed = true;
      } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)  {
            upPressed = true; 
      } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
            downPressed = true;
      }

}

   function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
       if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
           leftPressed = false;
       } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
           rightPressed = false;
       } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
           upPressed = false;
       } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
           downPressed = false;
       }


   }
/*
function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        leftReleased = true;
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        rightReleased = true;
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        upReleased = true;
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        downReleased = true;
    }

}*/



function loop(e:Event):void{


    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x, player.y + leftBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("leftBumping");
    leftBumping = true;
} else {
    leftBumping = false;
}


    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + rightBumpPoint.x, player.y + rightBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("rightBumping");
    rightBumping = true;
} else {
    rightBumping = false;
}
    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint.x, player.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("upBumping")
    upBumping = true;
} else { 
    upBumping = false;
}

    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("downBumping")
    downBumping = true;
    } else {
        downBumping = false;
    }

    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + upleftBumpPoint.x, player.y + upleftBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("upleftBumping")
    upleftBumping = true;
    } else {
        upleftBumping = false;
    }

    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + uprightBumpPoint.x, player.y + uprightBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("uprightBumping")
    uprightBumping = true;
    } else {
        uprightBumping = false;
    }

    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + downrightBumpPoint.x, player.y + downrightBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("downrightBumping")
    downrightBumping = true;
    } else {
        downrightBumping = false;
    }

    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + downleftBumpPoint.x, player.y + downleftBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("downleftBumping")
    downleftBumping = true;
    } else {
        downleftBumping = false;
    }




        if(leftPressed){
        xSpeed -= speedConstant ;
    } else if(rightPressed){
        xSpeed += speedConstant;
    } else if(upPressed){
        ySpeed += speedConstant;
    } else if(downPressed){
        ySpeed -= speedConstant;
    }



    if(leftBumping){
        if(xSpeed < 0){
        xSpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}

if(rightBumping){
    if(xSpeed > 0){
        xSpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}

if(upBumping){
    if(ySpeed < 0){
        ySpeed *= -0.5;
    } 
}

if(downBumping){
    if(ySpeed > 0){
        ySpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}
    xSpeed *= friction;
    ySpeed *= friction;

    scrollX -= xSpeed;
    scrollY += ySpeed;

    back.x = scrollX;
    back.y = scrollY;

}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include how your program works?  What is the background in relation to the player?   (usually a background is just a background and doesn't need to interact with anything)

Comment: Have you considered just using a physics engine?

Comment: Ok, I have found something called Box2DFlash. I will play around with it and see if it solves my problem. If you can still find a solution I will be very grateful.

Comment: The solution, is to break your `back` object into individual rectangles and hitTestObject those with player, if the hit test succeeds, move the player to the edge of that rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't analyzed whole your code but it just seems like typical bullet scenario.
If you testing only one point against an obstacle which width is less then player speed you will occasionally miss the obstacle because in one frame the test point is on one side of it and in next frame on the other - point is not hitting it on both frames.
The easiest way to fix it is just to make sure your obstacles have width greater than speed of your player.
Another way is to test intermediate points between positions of your test points. You can do this easly through `Point.interplate()` method and additionally you can also adjust number of intermediate tests according to your player speed and size of obsticles.
But since you started with Box2D, you can just set a bullet flag in objects physics properties.